# Increasing the size of the custom objects array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a class Student and the dynamically created array of students:

```
class Student{
public:
  void create(){
    system("cls");
    cout << "First name: ";
    cin >> fn;
    cout << "Last name: ";
    cin >> ln;
    cout << "How many subjects? ";
    cin >> sub_number;
    subjects = new string[sub_number];
    for(int i = 0; i < sub_number; i++){
      cout << "Subject name: ";
      cin >> subject[i];
    }
  }

  //This just display the student with a bunch of couts
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Student&);

  ~Student(){ delete[] subjects; }
private:
  string fn;
  string ln;
  string* subjects;
  int sub_number;
};
```

**I need to increase the size of this array by 1 and add a new student to it.**

When I tried to do it by simply:

```
void main(){
   int stu_number = 0;
   cout << "How many students? "
   cin >> stu_number;
   Student* students = new Student[stu_number];

   //creating/updating initial students using user input
   for(int i = 0; i < stu_number; i++){
     students[i].create();
   }

   //displaying all students
   for(int i = 0; i < stu_number; i++){
     cout << students[i];
   }

   //trying to add a student
   add_new_student(students, stu_number);

   //displaying all students again
   for(int i = 0; i < stu_number; i++){
     cout << students[i];
   }
}
```

And the **add_new_student** function:

```
void add_new_student(Student* students, int& stu_number){
  Student* temp = new Student[stu_number++];
  for (int i = 0; i < stu_number - 1; i++){
    temp[i] = students[i];
  }
  temp[stu_number - 1].create(); 
  delete[] students;
  students = temp;
}
```

I am getting memory violation errors and Unhandled exceptions: Access violation writing location 0xABABABAB inside the add_new_student function.

- What will be the correct way of doing this?
- Is Student class missing some important components?

I can't use `std::vector` or a `std::list` as this is a school assignment:)

Comment: You need to show more code with more context. For example *where* do you "increase" the size? In a function? Do you pass the pointer by value or by reference? And ***where*** do the crash happen? Run in a debugger to locate it. And can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Stop this madness and use `std::vector`. It is a zero-overhead, implementation of resizable, dynamically allocated arrays. Why would you not use `std::vector` if you are doing C++.

Comment: Oh, and what does `Student` look like? Do you perhaps need a copy-assignment operator? You might want to read about [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_) (alternatively about [the rule of zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html)).

Comment: @FélixCantournet They mentioned this is for a class assignment and they cannot use `std::vector` or `std::list`. That is not uncommon in coursework for learning purposes.

Comment: The only "dynamic" here is *dynamically allocated*. Once allocated, there is nothing more "dynamic" about it: it won't change size! C++ container classes are *dynamic* in the sense that they change size dynamically as needed.

Comment: What exactly is `Student`?  What does `create()` really do?

Comment: hopefully you can use `std::unique_ptr<Student[]>` at least!

Comment: @Cyber I know. it is not uncommon for bad teachers to try to miss the point of encapsulation and instead of teaching people how to **USE** `std::vector` and then **AFTER** teaching them how to implement it, they mix the two and produces thousands upon thousands of terrible "C-style" C++ programmers. But I guess resistance is futile...

Comment: @Cyber - `That is not uncommon in coursework for learning purposes`  Yeah, learning how to be frustrated.  Then switch to Java.  Seriously, I have yet to see a student code this correctly *and* be told how to write it correctly, unless they come here or go to a similar site.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a good way to go about it, I remember having to do that kind of stuff when I was in school. If I could go back, I'm sure I'd have some recommendations for the professors now that I've been around the block.

Comment: Stop advising him to use std:: containers/utilities. Learning C++ often begins in understanding how things work internally. He was told to implement this without `vector`, so "use `std::vector`" is not an answer. "Switch to Java" isn't either.
@Kocur4D Post code of `Student` class, please. Except for memory leak, there is no error in this code. Probably something bad is happening when you copy elements from old array to the new one.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek `"Use Java" isn't either.`  That wasn't what was recommended.  That is what students do when they get C++ frustration given assignments like this that really want to write real programs.  Second, this is the comment section -- answers would go in the answer section.

Comment: `I don't think that it is impotent to know how create() works `  If I had a dollar for every time supposedly non-important code *is* important in answering the question, I would be a rich man.

Comment: @ALL : If use std::vector isn't the answer then the answer is implement a nicely contained abstraction for resizable array (i.e; std::vector, but simpler). NOT "do this crappy management of memory in the middle of your business logic".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Amen to that.

Comment: ABABABAB is a memory overflow - accessing memory outside the allocated range.  To help more we need to know exactly what line of code gives that error - the debugger should tell you that.

Comment: `and it is still not correct way to increase the size of this array`  Your code is on a high-level, correct in the way to resize the array.  The issue is that there is much more going on than just resizing the array.  You are assigning one Student object to another within the loop, and we have no idea if `Student` has correct copy semantics.  You also call `create()`, and we don't know if that function causes memory corruption in some way.

Comment: What does the [default constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29258043/2932052) do? You have one right?

Comment: I'm going to be psychic and guess that `Student` itself uses `char *` member variables instead of  `std::string`, and improper usage of these members is causing the fault.

Comment: Updated the answer with more code. After reading comments I think I know where the problem is now but I will not do any more assumptions today. Thank you for all the suggestions. I have learned my lesson!

Comment: @Kocur4d you write *`I am getting memory violation errors and Unhandled exceptions: Access violation writing location 0xABABABAB inside the add_new_student function.`* - but this is important: **where** do you get the exception? can you point at the statement in the code?

Comment: @wolf I know:( but I don't have this information atm(I will get crucified for this) basically I was helping some with this code and I don't have a stack installed on my computer to recreate it:/

Comment: @Kocur4d - Well, my psychic powers were almost spot on:  `string* subjects;`  Do you see that your homework problem has become a catch-22 issue here?  You are trying to implement a dynamic array, but your `Student` class itself needs to have a dynamic array of string implemented.  The comment that you should be developing a vector class, and not do this one-off attempt of allocating and deallocating memory in business logic has turned out to be prophetic.  If you make copies of your `Student` object, you will be erroneously destroying your data due to the destructor being called.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie agree 100%, I am a Ruby person. In my world thing are happening(and de-happening) magically. Puff! My sister is taking C++ Uni classes and I didn't get used to(forget) about the evil land of C++ where the pointers and memory allocation will chase you down:) She was told that she can't use the std::vector. Maybe it was a good call, it will teach you to use it all the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `Student` class does not follow the "rule of 3":

[What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

If your class has a user-defined destructor, then it should also provide a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator.  What is happening now is that when this line is performed:

`temp[i] = student[i];`

you are invoking the assignment operator.  However, your `Student` object, when assigned, will just copy the pointer value from one object to the other.  What happens when the `destructor` for either of these `Student` objects is called?  The destructor will delete the same pointer value twice, thus an error.

Here is a slimmed down version of your current `Student` class.

```
#include <string>

class Student
{
      std::string* subjects;
      std::string fn;
      std::string ln;
      int sub_number;

   public:
      Student(size_t numSubjects=5) : subjects(new std::string[numSubjects]), 
                                      sub_number(numSubjects){} 

      ~Student() { delete [] subjects; }
};

// Test code
int main()
{
    Student s1(10);
    Student s2 = s1;
    Student s3;
    s3 = s1;
}
```

If you run this program, you will see that there are problems with memory leaks and double deletion errors, as shown here:  http://ideone.com/MQhpcK

All I'm doing is copying `Student` objects, and the issue appears.

To fix the problem, you must add and implement these functions in your `Student` class:

```
      Student(const Student& rhs);  // copy constructor
      Student& operator=(const Student& rhs); // assignment operator
```

Once you implement these functions, test the program above to ensure it truly does make the copies correctly, without memory leaks and segmentation faults/access violation errors.  When done, your original issue of the copying causing the access violation should be resolved.

Answer (score 5):

To increase the size of the array, you basically have to:

- Create a new array with a larger size
- Copy over the values from the old smaller array to the new larger one
- Delete the old smaller array

That being said, if you are able to I would recommend switching to `std::vector` since it has utility methods that will resize for you.

Comment: Also note that your last line `students = temp` leaks the old array that `students` used to point to.

Comment: `std:vector` - definitely! ...if this was really a C++ question ;-)

Comment: @Wolf i can't use std:vector, it is silly but I can't

Comment: @Kocur4d all but `std::vector` would not be C++, maybe you can do something against such stupid rules? Why does this school teach nonsense?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by the missing assignment operator. In the assignment within the for loop, there is a flat copy of the subjects array which is deleted when the original students array is deleted. After that, there is a so-called dangling pointer in first Student object.

The [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator) has the job to safely (and semantically correct) copy all elements from one object to another.

**Additionally:** It would be really interesting (informative) to add some trace output as to get a detailed understanding what's going on here.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on assignment operator? maybe you can draft a possible method. I will correct it if it will be wrong as soon as I will get access to the code?

Comment: I will add more info about errors as soon as I will get a chance to try assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever `create` is called for<sup>[1]</sup>, there must be something wrong with the default constructor<sup>[2]</sup> of your `Student` class: it seems to miss initializing important elements that are used within `create`.

---

- <sup>[1]</sup> BTW: what is the purpose of `create`?
- <sup>[2]</sup> Is there a default constructor? What C++ standard is used?